# INSERT INTO excluding ID column violates primary key uniqueness constraint

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a Postgres 10.6 table with a `serial` ID column.

When I attempt to insert into it:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
```

excluding the ID column from the column list, I get:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customer_invoice_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1234) already exists.
```

Subsequent runs of the query increment the ID in the error message (1235, 1236 etc.)

How can this be happening?

Comment: Posting at least part of your table definition would help figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `serial` column does not prevent you from inserting rows with an explicit value for `id`. The sequence value is only a default value that is used when `id` is not specified in the `INSERT` statement.

So there must have been some “rogue” inserts of that kind. From PostgreSQL v11 on, you can use identity columns (`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`) to make overriding the sequence value harder.

You could use the `setval` function to set the sequence to a value higher than the maximum `id` in the table to work around the problem.

Comment: Yes: this. Haven't checked it yet, but that sounds exactly right.

Comment: Checked now and this was exactly the problem. +100 for the "rogue inserts" concept. Exactly correct and funny!